# Users gsettings ubuntu 18.4

Tags: scripts, gsettings

I have a doubt. I currently have a script ... which I run when I finish installing Ubuntu 18.

And I don't know how I can add gsettings when executing it ... here is a sample of how it starts.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
######### is username and password entered? ########
if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
echo "Username and password required."
echo "Example:"
echo "sh script-sessions users password"
exit
fi
USER = $ 1
PASSWORD = $ 2
######### is running as root? #########
me=$(whoami)
if [ "root" = $ yo ]
then
         threw out ""
else
         echo "This command must be run as administrator, run sudo su"
         exit
fi
######### Does the user exist in the system? ########

exists=$ (cat /etc/passwd | grep "$ USER:")
if [ -n "$ exists" ]; then
echo "User exists"
else
echo "The user does not exist, enter a system user."
exit
fi
```

Comment: Add gsettings to do what?

Comment: ine gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop font 'Cantarell 9' but being root does not take the changes, but its done without being root, if it applies. What I need is to do it in the script, because if not, I have to wait for it to finish, get out of the root, and then run that line to make the change ... I don't know if I was clear?